# Is it possible to share value between 2 classes inherited from same class - python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Please find the code below

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.b1 = kwargs['a']
       self.b2 = kwargs['b']

class Child1(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.c = kwargs['c']
       super(Child1).__init__(**kwargs)
       print(self.b1)
       print(self.b2)

    def call(self):
       self.b1 -= 10
       self.b2 -= 20

class Child2(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.c = kwargs['c']
       super(Child2).__init__(**kwargs)
       print(self.b1)
       print(self.b2)
```

When I call using the below:

```
obj1 = Child1(a=20,b=30,c=5)
obj1.call()   #output 20, 30
obj2 = Child2(c=5)
```

I want the output of b1 and b2 to be reflected since obj1 has already changed the value

Please advice

Comment: Why do you use `super(Base, self)` instead of `super(Child, self)` or `super()` in `Child` class?

Comment: wanted to initialize it?

Comment: But is there a way to share the values from base class to be used in child class (changed value)?

Comment: `super(Base, self)` indicates `object` class in your code. You should use `super(Child, self)` or `super()` to indicates `Base` class.

Comment: Got it ..changed it in the post

Comment: 'since obj1 has already changed the value ..' that's wrong. obj1 changed the values inside obj1's namespace whereas obj2 dosn't even have attrubues `b1` and `b2`

Comment: Oh okay. Is there any way I can make the value b1 and b2 shareable using inheritance concept ?

Comment: you can change this line `obj2 = Child2(c=5)` to this one `obj2 = Child2(c=5,b = obj1.b1, a = obj1.b2)` and you should add `self` to`super` it should be `super(Child1, self)` and `super(Child2, self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
class Base:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.b1 = kwargs['a']
       self.b2 = kwargs['b']
       Base.instances.append(self)


class Child1(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.c = kwargs['c']
       super(Child1,self).__init__(**kwargs)
       print(self.b1)
       print(self.b2)

    def call(self):
       self.b1 -= 10
       self.b2 -= 20


class Child2(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.c = kwargs['c']
        super(Child2,self).__init__(a = Base.instances[0].b1, b = Base.instances[0].b2)
        print(self.b1)
        print(self.b2)



obj1 = Child1(a=20,b=30,c=5)
obj1.call()   
obj2 = Child2(c=5)
```

All new instances initiated with `Base` are saved inside `Base.instances`. Then you can take the first one and use its `b1` and `b2` attributes when you create something from `Child2` class.